# Does the following groupoid have an identity element/zero element?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$ (\mathbb{R} ,\circ)$, where $ a \circ b=ab+a+b$

Should I check somehow properties, to find the solution?

Comment: Yes, checking properties is always a good idea in such cases. Alternatively, you may also wonder what $c$ is if $(a-1)\circ (b-1)=(c-1)$

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't see any relationship with your comment to my question. How did you get this $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \in \mathcal{R}$ and define $e :=0$. Then:

$$a \cdot e = ae + e + a = 0+0+a = a.$$
You can easily check that $e \cdot a$ results in the same.

Thus, $e$ is the identity element.

Comment: If I say that $b:=0$ than I get that $a \cdot b=0+a+0$ so I can say, that it has no zero element?

Comment: No, this shows (almost, you need to do show $b \cdot a = a$ still) that b is the zero/identity element.

Comment: Can you maybe help me, how can I show it, in  this special case? (I mean this zero element thing)

Comment: Are you looking for an element such that $a \cdot x = 0$ for all a? It does'nt exist and you can convice yourself by considering $1\cdot x$ and $2\cdot x$.